# Make SingleChildScrollView scrollable as one with child widgets like a carousel slider and a gridview widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Inside a scaffold() widget I have a SingleChildScrollView. Inside the SingleChildScrollView I'm trying to show a Carousel slider and just below it a GridView.

Part of my code is :-

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                FutureBuilder<PscResponse>(.....),
                SizedBox(...),
                  Expanded(
                    child: PagedGridView<int, Psgrow>(
                        showNewPageProgressIndicatorAsGridChild: true,
                        showNewPageErrorIndicatorAsGridChild: true,
                        showNoMoreItemsIndicatorAsGridChild: true,
                        pagingController: _contPsg,
                        // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                          maxCrossAxisExtent: 330,
                          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                          mainAxisExtent: 205,
                        ),
                        builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Psgrow>(
                            itemBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, Psgrow item, int index) {
                          return PSGItemWidget();
         ..................
         ..................
```

When I run the app, I want the carousel widget and the gridview widget to scroll as one. At present what is happening is that the gridview widget is scrollable but to scroll the SingleChildScrollView I have to click the carousel.

Inside the gridview widget when I write `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`, the SingleChildScrollView is scrollable as one but the gridview widget is not scrollable.

I'm not able to scroll the SingleChildScrollView with all its child widgets to scroll as one. I hope I'm able to express my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be right just remove the Sizedbox which you have used to wrap the Column becz of this your column isn't able to expand as much as the GridView requires Also you dont need to give Scroll Direction as its default Scroll is vertical.